# How to make workplace selector 2x2 instead of 4x1?

Tags: unity

I'm having a problem with workplace configuration - it appears as a 4x1 box when I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>. I have 2x2 box at the other installation (was that way since the start), so how can I make it this way instead of 4x1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to install compizconfig-settings-manager. The quickest way is from the terminal. Open a terminal (CNRT + ALT +T) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open the newly installed compizconfig-settings-manager and under "General Options" set the desktop size to 2 horizontal and 2 vertical, it should look like this:

[image: screenshot compizconfig-settings-manager]

Note that you should be careful with compizconfig-settings-manager you can break your system if you do not know what you are doing!

Comment: I have *exactly* this setting already. But the stuff from `ccsm` isn't working for me! Same as the launcher panel visibility, which I tried to set to never. I've tried `unity --reset`, but it didn't help...

Comment: I know this is the right answer since I've done some research meanwhile, so I'll mark it as such. I'll make a new question regarding the ccsm problem

Comment: Here is the new question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/96070/cssm-doesnt-work Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your other question, it seems that you are using Unity 2D.  There is no way to reconfigure the workspace layout seen when switching workspaces with the keyboard shortcuts.

While it is unlikely that they will add such a configuration option, the current 4x1 presentation is considered a bug and future versions should show the expected 2x2 layout:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/715587

You can temporarily change the layout for the current login session with the following command though:

```
xprop -root -f _NET_DESKTOP_LAYOUT 32cccc -set _NET_DESKTOP_LAYOUT 0,2,2,0
```

Comment: When unity-2d will get some substantial upgrade in 11.10 isn't quite clear, users that want to see the fix for this & some other improvements can consider using the unity-2d daily ppa which is safe to use & not a daily ppa at all, last unity-2d for 11.10 was on 12/06/11.. https://launchpad.net/~unity-2d-team/+archive/unity-2d-daily