# CCSM doesn't work when changing launcher visibility or number of workspaces

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz

The compizconfig setting manager doesn't work on my `11.10` installation of Ubuntu. I've tried setting the launcher panel visibility to "never" and changing the number of workspaces in the virtual box, but it doesn't affect the actual system, not even after rebooting.

I have the same setup on a desktop PC and there everything is just working - this problem only appears on the laptop.

I've tried `unity --reset` and `compiz --replace` to no avail. I would be very thankful for any suggestions on how to get it working

**Update:**

Ok, so I've dug a bit more and it seems that I'm running Unity 2D. It stays that way regardless of what I select at the login screen

Comment: looks like you were quicker than me :-)

Comment: have you checked if your graphics card supports Unity? http://askubuntu.com/a/34583/33871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably running unity 2d which is not powered by compiz (so ccsm settings wount affect your desktop session)

To see if you are running unity 2d check [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62001/am-i-using-unity-or-unity-2d)